# Unable to copy Ruby object's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very painful issue here, if some one could help ?

I have a class Task with attributes and I wanted to make a bang method (because I'm changing the receiver) but I'm not able to change object attributes properly :

```
def reject!
    return nil if self.previous_owner.nil?
    self.delegate = false

    # Before, owner equal a User object
    self.owner = self.previous_owner # previous_owner is also a User object, but different
    self.previous_owner = nil

    return self if self.save
    raise "Can't save object"
end
```

This won't work because self.owner will be nil...
I know this is because telling Ruby that self.owner = self.previous_owner and then changing self.previous_owner to nil.

So how can I avoid this ? I tried clone and dup method, but I'm not sure I want to have a new copied User object...

Strange thing too, if I try this in rails console :

```
a = 'Foo'
b = a
a = 'New value'

puts a # "New value"
puts b # "Foo"
```

So I think I'm missing something...

Comment: What do the accessor methods for owner look like - anything non-standard happening there?  Or the `@=` method in the user object?  Try `@owner` instead of `self.owner`?  Try `self.owner, self.previous_owner = self.previous_owner, nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that `self.owner` and `self.previous_owner` are convenience methods provided by Rails. The actual fields should be called something like `owner_id` and `previous_owner_id` and contain the actual id of the `User` you want to link to.

So a simpler, and failsafe approach is to write

```
self.owner_id = self.previous_owner_id
self.previous_owner = nil # this will unlink the previous owner
self.save!
```

and `self.save!` will raise if the save fails.

Comment: Thx it works ! However, do you know how I could stop doing myObject.reload after calling reject ? Or is it normal to do so ?

Comment: Remark: in ruby we do not camel-case variables. It is considered ugly :) If you need to access the `owner` after the reject, and you accessed the `owner` before, you will need to do `reload` indeed.